# How to resolve magento2 module conflictions

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I installed module conflict detector module. I found 4 conflictions in my magento. https://github.com/magefan/module-conflict-detector

Please find attached image for referance. But i don't know how to resolve these conflictions . can any body help me on this? I tried to add sequence in my second module as below.but its not resolved any conflictions.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Soulof_Vincrequest" setup_version="2.0.2" release_version="1.0.1">
    <sequence>
        <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
            <module name="My_RequestToQuote" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

You can achieve this in below way.

1. Merge your code into one file and remove the unnecessary file.
2. You can do extends that class to another class

Like 
Extension A class extend to Core Class
Extension B class extend to Core Class

so you can create extend clas like Extension A class extend to Extension B.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the two files to avoid conflict. For Example, you have two files `Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Search\Result\Index`, `Smartwave\Porto\Controller\CatalogSearch\Result\Index`. These two files extend the core class `Magento\CatalogSearch\Result\Index` which does create conflict here. So you can remove those Classes and merge it to a single class in your custom module which does solve the conflict and functionality of modules remains unaltered.